# Amazon Spot Price History - Java Code

Tags: java, sdk, amazon-ec2

It should be possible to get the AWS Spot Price history for the past 90 days. When using the Java SDK it's possible to create a query to get some of the history, but because this list is so long they split it up. Using a token you should be able to get the next part of the list, en this until you have received the whole list.

The problem is that using the given token I was not yet able to retrieve more then the first part of the list. While searching the internet it became clear that my understanding of this token is right.

```
    // Create the AmazonEC2Client object so we can call various APIs.
    AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);

    // Get the spot price history
    DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult result = ec2.describeSpotPriceHistory();

    // Print first part of list
    for (int i = 0; i < result.getSpotPriceHistory().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(result.getSpotPriceHistory().get(i));
    }

    result = result.withNextToken(result.getNextToken());

    // Print second part of list
    for (int i = 0; i < result.getSpotPriceHistory().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(result.getSpotPriceHistory().get(i));
    }
```

The "nextToken" of the result is not changing. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is there a bug in the SDK? I installed it via Eclipse.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed not using the API as expected - you need to resubmit the [DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest.html) with the `nextToken` retrieved from the [DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult.html) (admittedly it is slightly confusing that you can set `nextToken` on the latter as well, guess it should ideally be an internal method only), e.g:

```
// Create the AmazonEC2Client object so we can call various APIs.
AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);

// Get the spot price history
String nextToken = "";
do {
    // Prepare request (include nextToken if available from previous result)
    DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest request = new DescribeSpotPriceHistoryRequest()
            .withNextToken(nextToken);

    // Perform request
    DescribeSpotPriceHistoryResult result = ec2
            .describeSpotPriceHistory(request);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.getSpotPriceHistory().size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(result.getSpotPriceHistory().get(i));
    }

    // 'nextToken' is the string marking the next set of results returned (if any), 
    // it will be empty if there are no more results to be returned.            
    nextToken = result.getNextToken();

} while (!nextToken.isEmpty());
```